# Dynamic changing of mg-tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, angular2-md-tabs

Dynamic changing of tabs is realised with attribute md-selected="selectedTab". Function in controller change selectedTab. It works perfectly while I not changing tabs manually, or put a default value of (selectedTab = 1).

Comment: What is the exact question here? Or do you have any code so far that you can show?

Comment: The question is "how can I dynamicaly change tabs after i have changed it  manualy"

Comment: I have dicrovered that md-tabs creates its own scope when I change tab manualy first time